# Is sending mail from local machine with no encryption unsafe

Tags: email, encryption

note: I'm working on wordpress but this isn't a wordpress question.

I have a wordpress site sitting on my local machine and I need it to send emails to newly registered users.
I managed doing it with a plugin.
As a mail server I'm using the SMTP server of the host of my online websites (justhost).
The settings I'm using are:

SMTP Host: mail.mydomain.com
SMTP Port: 2626
Authentication: SMTP authentication
username: my username on justhost
password: my password on justhost

In the Encryption setting I chose no encryption, since this is the only way I managed sending a mail. SSL encryption didn't work.

So my question is: is this unsafe? Are the message contents exposed?
And more importantly - are my username and password exposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an attacker between you and your SMTP server he can intercept the message. And I think your password is exposed too.

But why don't you simply look into your traffic with wireshark?

Comment: so he can intercept the message only when it's sent?
I mean - it can't be intercepted an hour after it's been sent, right?
Wireshark's a good idea.

Comment: Tried wireshark. I saw the fields: To, From, message subject, message body. Didn't see the user and password. But - when new users register they get their first password in the message body. So, it's a problem.